# Binary Search gives Index Out of Bound Exception in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, binary

I am trying to implement binary search using java programming language. 
it's obvious that the array should be sorted in order to make use of binary search because it uses divide and conquer concept. The code works fine for both cases when the when the element is within the array and when it's not. But, when I enter a number that is greater than the greatest number inside the array, the program will crash and give Index Out Of Bound Exception.

```
public class Binary {

public static void search(int arr[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int upper = arr.length;
    int lower = 0;
    int middle = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int key;

    /*
     * flag = 0 ---> not found yet.
     * flag = 1 ---> element is found.
     * flag = 2 ---> no such element.
     */

    System.out.println("Enter the number that you want to find... ");
    key = in.nextInt();

    while (flag == 0) {
        middle = (int) (lower + upper) / 2;

        if (key == arr[middle]) {
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (key < arr[middle]) {
            upper = middle - 1;
        } else if (key > arr[middle]) {
            lower = middle + 1;
        }
        if (lower > upper) {
            flag = 2;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        System.out.println(arr[middle] + " has been found, its index is: "
                + middle);
    } else
        System.out.println("Error, no such element.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 34, 56 };
    search(arr);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
int upper = arr.length-1;
```

If you are looking for a number greater than the greatest, than you will sure look at the last element of the array. 
But in your code `upper` has an initial value that is 1 more than the index of the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can take MisterDev's solution and correct the upper bound. Usually, in Java arrays, the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound exclusive, however, and I like the idea that `lower` and `upper` follow this pattern.

Then, `lower < upper` means that the range isn't empty and the middle point will become the new exclusive upper bound when searching continues in the first half:

```
public static int search(int arr[], int key)
{
    int upper = arr.length;
    int lower = 0;

    while (lower < upper) {
        int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;

        if (key == arr[middle]) return middle;

        if (key < arr[middle]) {
            upper = middle;
        } else if (key > arr[middle]) {
            lower = middle + 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I've made the function take the key as a parameter and return the index or -1 if the key isn't found. Taking user input and the `flag` have no business in your code, in my opinion; you should write a wrapper for that, so that `Binary.search` really just does the search.

Comment: this is great. this way you can make it flexible and use it in some other programs.